# Why Bootstrap doesn't fit my whole row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying use Bootstrap in my website. In header I'd like to make a row with 2 columns: one at the left, one at the right and empty space between. So I wrote a code like below. Left column is exactly where I want to be - in the left corner.. But right column doesn't want to go to the right and I don't know why.

```
<header class="head">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zMcs5/60/. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks correct to me: https://jsfiddle.net/zMcs5/61/... Do you just want the text right aligned on the right column?

Comment: Your results change based on the size of your fiddle's result frame. Expand it and you will have your desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right column ***is*** in the correct position, but since the text is left-aligned by default, it may look like it's in the incorrect position. To fix this, either center-align both columns by using `text-center`, or left-align the left column (`text-left` or leave defaulted) and right-align the right column (`text-right`):

[Option 1](https://jsfiddle.net/zMcs5/64/)

```
<header class="head">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 text-center">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

[Option 2](https://jsfiddle.net/zMcs5/65/)

```
<header class="head">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Indeed, it was a problem with text align, not with position of column. It's everything clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap gets picky when you start mixing rows and columns. In my experience the "pull-right" class often needs to be in a different place to work correctly.

Part of your problem is putting two div tags of 12 grid widths wide in the same row. Since the Bootstrap grid is limited to 12 units wide, you can't ask for a total of 24. To keep things neat and even I adjusted those values, then added a "pull-right" class to your `<p>` div in the second column. You might want to just put an inline or block div in your second column with a "pull-right" class to keep all content inside it right justified.

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zMcs5/62/ 
Here are the big changes in a nutshell:

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <p class="pull-right">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

I hope this gets you going down the right path!